# Changing default Wi-Fi interface [command line]/automatic one with best connection

Tags: networking, wifi

How to make the Raspberry Pi
change the default Wi-Fi interface
to one with best connection at given moment
automatically/periodically?

Assuming:

- We have a few - >=2 - Wi-Fi interfaces.
- Interfaces are placed differently, so they might have different quality of signal/reach-ability
- The signal might change, so the best device might be different at different times

Example `iwconfig` for two devices, (might be for more):

```
$ iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"WIFI_ABC"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: ab:cd:ef:01:23:45   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=1496 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0                                                                                                                              
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0                                                                                                                              

lo        no wireless extensions.                                                                                                                                                               

eth0      no wireless extensions.                                                                                                                                                               

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"WIFI_ABC"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"                                                                                                                             
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: ab:cd:ef:01:23:45   
          Bit Rate:144.4 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=69/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Here is output of route:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.9.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
default         192.168.9.1     0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan1
192.168.9.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.9.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan1
```

P.S.

- "default interface" - e.g. used by `apt-get upgrade`, `aria2c` etc
- "best at given moment" - I am fine with abstracting this part to assumption that we have script `choose_best_wifi.sh`, that returns name of interface , e.g. "wlan0" or "wlan1" to its standard output. (I can make such script that makes few tests and probing)
- "periodically" - can be cronjob run every 15 minutes

Comment: Could you add the output of `route` when you have such a setup (two or more wlan interfaces, both connected) to your question please?

Comment: What I think you need to do is to change your `default` route to the appropriate interface (probably delete them both, then reinsert the right one), which you can do using the `route` command. I'll fiddle around with it when I have some time but perhaps this will get you started.

Comment: Thanks, once I come back to that device will play with `route` :).